# SendKeys method is not working when I am using keyword as sendkeys for keyword driven framework for selenium automation

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, frameworks, automated-tests

I am using selenium keyword driven framework to automate my project.

With current framework structure im able to launch chrome browser, enter url, click elements, however at login page I am not able to send keys in Username field. I have provided action as "sendKeys" and wrote a code inside my execution engine(Keyword Driven structure). The question is if Click action is working then why not sendkeys action.

Please follow the code snippet for sendkeys and click action.

```
switch (locatorName) {
            case "xpath":
                WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath(locatorValue));
                    if (actionCol.equalsIgnoreCase("enter")) {
                        element.clear();
                        element.sendKeys(valueCol);
                        System.out.println("SendKeys is implemented");
                    } else if (actionCol.equalsIgnoreCase("click")) {
                        element.click();
                        System.out.println("Click is implemented");
                    }
                    locatorName= null;
                    break;

            default:
                break;
}
```

Comment: I am using excel sheet for initiating my scenario steps. in that i have used "enter" as my action for entering user id in username field. as i have used below code to initiate the click and send keys command from selenium
if(actionCol.equalsIgnoreCase("enter")){ element.clear(); element.sendKeys(valueCol); System.out.println("SendKeys is implimented"); }else if(actionCol.equalsIgnoreCase("click")) { element.click(); System.out.println("Click is implimented"); } locatorName= null; break;

Comment: Can you show us the `valueCol` variable which is being passed into the `sendKeys` method?

Comment: valueCol is Alphanumeric value, which is been passed in send keys

Answer (score 0):

You can enter by text by pasting it.

Import these:

```
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
```

And then put this snippet of code wherever you'd like to alter the clipboard:

```
String OriginalString = "I'm gonna copy this";
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(OriginalString );
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
```